# Image title in Views replacement patterns?

Tags: views, 8, media

I can not seem to find the title token for images in replacement patterns in D8 views. In D7 it was [field_image-title] but there is no title option in D8. I have tried {{ field_image_title }} and {{ field_images-title }}.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The replacement pattern is:

```
{{ field_image__title }}
```

See this screenshot from Views:

[image: Replacement Patterns Image Field]

Comment: Weird, If you overwrite a field it is available, but if you use Global Text field it is not available. Thanks! [http://imgur.com/a/ujWNh](http://imgur.com/a/ujWNh)